# PHP Save string and variable to a array

Tags: php, variables

How do I save the string below with the variables to a array? It doesnt seem to work..

```
$str[] = {'name':'$data['name']','y':$data['values'],'key':'$data['key']'},
$str_str = implode(' ', $str);
echo $str_str;
```

Thanks.

Comment: That won't parse. What is the source of that string?

Comment: I basically want to save something like "{'name':'name123','y':y123,'key':'key123'}," into the array. The values "name123, y123 and key123 should be replaced with variables like $data['name123'] . these variables come from a database.

Comment: Does no seem to work is not an error. Post the actual error so we dont have to guess.

Comment: maybe you want smth like `$str[] = ['name'=>$data['name'],...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about basic array and string handling in PHP. Something like this should work:

```
$str[] = [
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'y' => $data['values'],
    'key' => $data['key']
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way is just use $str[] = json_encode($data);

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to save a JSON string into an array?

`$var[]` saves a value to the first available numeric key in the array `$var` 
The string you would like to save looks like a JSON string, if that's what you want you can do so by:

```
$var[] = json_encode($data)
```

If the data array contains the following:

```
Array
(
    [name] => value name
    [y] => value y
    [key] => value key
)
```

JSON encoding this array will give you:

```
{"name":"value name","y":"value y","key":"value key"}
```